Not able to upgrade contract using UUPS proxy in remix
I want to upgrade my contract. My contract inherits UUPS proxy. While I am upgrading contract through remix, it is redirecting me to hit function upgradeTo but the case is that upgradeTo doesn't exists in that proxy contract.
But while I am doing this same scenario on testnet. It is redirecting me to upgradeToAndCall and this function exists in proxy contract. And in this I am able to upgrade my contract.
Anyone, have a read and if I am doing something wrong. Please mention that also.

hard to answer without looking at the code.
